# decimal literal is more than LONG_LONG_MAX

Tags: c++, c++11

In the "C++ Primer" book it is said that decimal literals have the smallest type of `int`, `long` or `long long` in which the literal's value fits, and it is an error to use a literal that is too large to fit in the largest related type. So, i guess, that the max decimal literal is the max value `long long` can hold.
But I tried it: printed the max `long long` value, then a decimal literal higher. I thought it had to cause an error, but it was okay. I then tried to print a decimal literal higher than the `unsigned long long` max value - it wrapped around.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << LONG_LONG_MAX << endl;
    cout << 9223372036854775808 << endl;
    cout << ULONG_LONG_MAX << endl;
    cout << 18446744073709551616 << endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775808
18446744073709551615
0
```

Explain please, why a decimal literal can be higher than the `long long` max value

**UPD**:

I noticed that there actually were warnings. I work under CodeBlocks, and on rebuilding and reruning your project it doesn't print warnings again, if the code isn't changed. So I just didn't notice. There were 3 warnings:

```
integer constant is so large that it is unsigned (8)
this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 (8)
integer constant is too large for its type (10)
```

But output was the same. Then I noticed that in debugger options I forgot to fill in the 'executable path' line, so I pasted there my gdb path. But I don't think it mattered.
Afterwards I noticed that I didn't choose the 'have g++ follow c++11' option in compiler settings. I did choose and compiler then printed both warnings and some errors. There wasn't the `this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90` warning, but was an `..\main.cpp|8|error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and '<unnamed-signed:128>')|` error. Also it didn't recognise `limits` with LONG_LONG_MAX and ULONG_LONG_MAX, but recognised `climits` with LLONG_MAX and ULLONG_MAX.
With c++98 there were warnings like in the first case (without any option chosen) and it didn't recognise `limits`, only `climits`. When I changed the header name, the output was like in the beginning. 
The compiler is set to GNU GCC Compiler.

Maybe someone could explain why compiler supports `limits` if I don't specify standard, and then, I think, the question is closed.

Comment: `unsigned long long` has a larger maximum value.

Comment: This is because you need a better compiler. `gcc` correctly issues a diagnostic for a tool-large integer constant. "integer constant is so large that it is unsigned" for the first constant, and "integer constant is too large for its type" for the second constant.

Comment: @OP -- *why a decimal literal can be higher than the long long max value* -- Did the compiler warn you on this code?  If so and you ignored the warnings, you took the gamble running a program that clearly has issues.

Comment: Is that really your code? The numeric limit macros are defined in `<climits>`, not in `<limits>`, and they're spelled `LLONG_MAX` and `ULLONG_MAX`, not `LONG_LONG_MAX` and `ULLONG_MAX`. *Always* copy-and-paste your actual code into the question. Please update your question to show the actual code you compiled along with any diagnostics printed by your compiler (even if they're just warnings).

Comment: @KeithThompson LONG_LONG_MAX and such (e.g. __LONG_LONG_MAX) actually are a thing, but not standardized. I met working code with that on cygwin, suppose that's a POSIX thing

Comment: `limits.h` and `climits` contain same things. `limits` is a completely different header.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat then why (I set c++11) doesn't `limits.h` support `ULLONG_MAX`, whereas `climits` does? And if you know, why does `limits` work okay without any standard chosen in options if you just use `ULONG_LONG _MAX` instead of `ULLONG_MAX`?

Comment: @SviatozarPetrenko In your question you mention `limits`, not `limits.h`. Which one is it? The `ULONG_LONG_MAX` is a compiler extension, and probably is disabled when you specify a `-std=c++XX` standard (instead of `-std=gnu++XX`, which seems to be the default).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, thanks!

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The code in the question doesn't compile for me on Cygwin using g++ 6.4.0. `LONG_LONG_MAX` isn't defined by POSIX. (There's no reason it would be; `LLONG_MAX` is already defined by the C standard.)

Comment: LONG_LONG_MAX might be defined in limits.h, <sys\limits.h> or <climits> or <limits>  on system I tried, it _did_ compile, but it isn't a standard thing and should not be used, it's an internal constant (and header inspection showed that LLONG_MAX was defined though it). You accused OP of falsifying code, while all he had was unportable code. It depends not only on compiler but on OS too. Wandbox compiles it with <climits> instead of <limits>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the language specification, a decimal literal with no suffix has a signed type (the smallest type of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` that can hold the value).  Binary, octal, and hexadecimal constants can have unsigned types.

An implementation is allowed to support *extended integer types*.  If your compiler has an integer type larger than a `long long`, then your decimal literal would be of that type.  If it doesn't, then it is either a compiler bug or compiler extension since an unsuffixed decimal literal cannot be of type `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use header and constants defined by standard. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits.

Upper limit for 64bit int (long long on most POSIX systems)     is 9223372036854775807 (2^63-1).
Maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int  18446744073709551615 (2^64-1).

`<limits>` may exists  but it not necessary includes `<climits>`.

As your literal doesn't fit into signed value, the compiler must have to give you diagnostic (if you didn't disabled it), something like

```
main.c:8:13: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
    cout << 9223372036854775808 << endl;
```

Apparently gcc\clang  are liberal enough to consider that enough and can compile program assuming that value would be represented with unsigned type, and to truncate the second literal. It's an *undetermined behavior* and former would not be true, so you may get negative values in output, e.g.:

```
9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
18446744073709551615
0
```

Comment: g++ and clang++ might assume that large integer constants are unsigned, but they print a warning which should **not** be ignored. Don't worry about how the code behaves if it compiles with warnings; just fix it.